# C++ When do I use -> or ::

Tags: c++, operators, expression, scope-resolution-operator

I know that in C++, you use either `->` or `::` instead of `.` in language such as C# to access object's values, e.g. `button->Text` or `System::String^`, but I don't know *when* I should use `->` or `::`, and it is very frustrating as it causes me many compiler errors. I would be very grateful if you could help. Thanks :)

Comment: Use -> when you're calling a function on a pointer to the object. :: Has several uses. One example is if you want to call a static function. The other is if you are implementing a function of a class. Have a look at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05cplr175.htm

Comment: You use `->`, or `.`, or occasionally `::`. It is not *instead of*.

Comment: `::` is scope resolution, `->` is indirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to show an examples of some usages of `::`, `.` and `->`. I hope it helps:

```
int g;

namespace test
{

  struct Test
  {
     int x;
     static void func();
  };

  void Test:: func() {
     int g = ::g;
  }

}

int main() {

  test::Test v;
  test::Test *p = &v;

  v.x = 1;
  v.func();
  p->x = 2;
  p->func();

  test::Test::func();

}
```

Comment: I try to avoid calling static methods on instances. It just seems confusing.

Comment: @clcto: It supposed to be an example and additionally shows we can call static methods in three ways.

Answer (score 10):

`->` is when you are accessing the member of a pointer variable.  EG: `myclass *m = new myclass(); m->myfunc();` Calls `myfunc()`  on pointer to `myclass`. `::` is the scoping operator. This is to show what scope something is in.  So if `myclass` is in namespace `foo` then you'd write `foo::myclass mc;`

Comment: You can also access public static members and internal typedefs using the scoping operator.

Answer (score 4):

- `->` if you have pointer to some object this is just shortcut for dereferencing that pointer and accessing its attribute.

  `pointerToObject->member` is the same as `(*pointerToObject).member`
- `::` Is for access stuff from some scope - it works only on namespaces and class/struct scopes.

  ```
  namespace MyNamespace {
    typedef int MyInt;
  }
  MyNamespace::MyInt variable;
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to what your question states, you *do* use `.` in C++. Quite a bit.

`.` (used with non-pointers to access members and methods)

```
std::string hello = "Hello";
if (hello.length() > 3) { ... }
```

`->` (used with pointers to access members and methods)

```
MyClass *myObject = new MyClass;
if (myObject->property)
    myObject->method();
```

`::` (scope resolution)

```
void MyClass::method() { ... } //Define method outside of class body

MyClass::static_property; //access static properties / methods
```

`::` is also used for namespace resolution (see first example, `std::string`, where `string` is in the namespace `std`).

Answer (score 2):

Opertor -> is applied when the left operand is a pointer. Consider for example

```
struct A
{
   int a, b;
   A( int a, int b ) : a( a ), b( this->a * b ) {}
};
```

Operator :: referes to the class or anmespace for which the right operand belongs. For example

```
int a;

strunt A
{
   int a;
   A( int a ) { A::a = a + ::a; }
};
```

The period is used then the left operand is lvalue of an object. For example

```
struct A
{
   int x;
   int y;
};

A *a = new A;

a->x = 10;
( *a ).y = 20;
```